# Can I install a sink with a drain pipe that's 21" off the floor?

Tags: sink, installation

We are trying to install a bathroom sink.  They had a step up to go into he small area where they apparently had a sink. They had replaced this tiny bathroom for a closet, but we are trying to place a sink again.  The drain pipe is 21 inches high.  Can we still mount a sink without having drainage problems?  What do we have to do?  Vilma and Joe

Comment: Welcome to SE. Is the step still part of the equation? If not, you might edit to remove that as it's confusing. What's your vanity height? We can't say without knowing that.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, your drain pipe is coming out of the wall 21" from the ground?

That's fine, provided you can connect it to the sink properly.

Vanity height is anywhere from 29" to 36". The old "standard height" was 32", however often new construction uses kitchen height or "comfort height" at 36".

A typical bathroom sink basin is from 5 to 9" deep.

A side view of the drain connection looks like this:

[image]

So if you have a 32" high vanity, with a 7" deep sink (outside dimension), that gives you about 4" for the tail piece connections, which is somewhat tight but should be enough room.

If you go to a 36" high vanity, you can do a deeper sink.

---

This doesn't directly answer your question about having drainage problems, however. What I'd be concerned about there is venting. For 1 1/2" pipe, there must be a vent within 3.5' of the trap:

[image]

I'm not sure what the status of your project is (eg, if you have access inside the walls to verify the plumbing), but it's easier to validate and fix this problem if necessary *before* you install a cabinet, sink, tile, paint, etc.